# Scraping a web page as you manually navigate

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

Is there a way, using some library or method, to scrape a webpage in real time as a user navigates it manually? Most scrapers I know of such as [python mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) create a browser object that emulates a browser - of course this is not what I am looking for since if I have a browser open, it will be different than the one mechanize creates.

If there is no solution, my problem is I want to scrape elements from a HTML5 game to make an intelligent agent of sorts. I won't go into more detail, but I suspect if others are trying to do the same in the future (or any real time scraping with a real user), a solution to this could be useful for them as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your use-case is, you could set up a [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy or some other form of proxy and configure it to log all traffic, then instruct your browser to use it.  You'd then scrape that log somehow.

Similarly, if you have control over your router, you could configure capture and logging there, e.g. using `tcpdump`.  This wouldn't decrypt encrypted traffic, of course.

If you are working with just one browser, there may be a way to instruct it to do something at each action via a custom browser plugin, but I'd have to guess you'd be running into security model issues a lot.

The problem with a HTML5 game is that typically most of its "navigation" is done using a lot  of Javascript.  The Javascript is typically doing a lot -- manipulating the DOM, triggering requests for new content to fit into the DOM, etc...

Because of this you might be better off looking into OS-level or browser-level scripting services that can "drive" keyboard and mouse events, take screenshots, or possibly even take a snapshot of the current page DOM and query it.

You might investigate browser automation and testing frameworks like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) for this.

Comment: Thank you - I was looking at computer vision type stuff but I didn't want to get into that if I didn't have to. While for my case - it is specifically one piece of information I need to scrape, I might be able to do it with a browser plugin, but I looked into SOCKS as suggested and it looks like a good alternative if others don't have that option.

Comment: Selenium and other browser testing frameworks may be easier than the SOCKS option, should probably have put those first.  I think you can drive Selenium and others using many different languages -- pretty sure they have hooks for python, perl, C#, ruby, and on and on...  My guess is you're looking for the presence or absence of certain objects, and peeking into the DOM to see if they're there may be easier than parsing HTML and JavaScript and other traffic and inferring what's going on.  On the other hand, if your game has a well-defined easy-to-read non-encrypted protocol, proxy is good.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work in your situation but it is possible to create a simple web browser using PyQt which will work with HTML5 and from this it might be possible to capture what is going on when a live user plays the game.

I have used PyQt for a simple browser window (for a completely different application) and it seems to handle simple, sample HTML5 games. How one would delve into the details of what is going on the game is a question for PyQt experts, not me.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to look into it some more.